# SQL Delete Rows group by column names and value less than the latest column values

Tags: sql-server

SQL Table,

```
Time1         Time2           Country    State 
May 9 12 PM   May 1 12 PM     USA        WA
May 9 12 PM   May 3 12 PM     USA        AK
May 8 12 PM   May 4 12 PM     USA        WA
May 8 12 PM   May 6 12 PM     USA        AK
```

What I want is for the latest Time1 get values of Time2 grouped by Country, State
and delete all rows which has time1 > time2

Comment: Asked the question properly if you really want this answer.

Comment: Can you reword your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my partial understanding of your question, I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
DELETE t
FROM SQL_TABLE t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(time1) time1
        ,country
        ,STATE
    FROM sql_table
    GROUP BY country
        ,STATE
    ) q1 ON q1.country = t.country
    AND q1.[State] = t.[state]
    and q1.time1 = t.Time1
WHERE q1.time1 > t.time2
```

In order to find the "latest" Time1 for given Country and State, you will need to find the `MAX` value and group by country and state. This query will then need to be joined back to the base table using all three fields (state,country, time1) and then use a `WHERE` clause to limit your `DELETE` statement. Hope this helps!

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b9e9/7/1)